# Uber error code in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, uber-api

I have integrated Uber iOS SDK and now working sandbox mode. Here is my ride request code.

```
[[UberHelper sharedInstance].ridesClient requestRideWithParameters:_rideParameters completion:^(UBSDKRide * _Nullable ride, UBSDKResponse * _Nonnull response) {NSLog(@"ERROR %@",response.error.title); NSLog(@"ERROR %@",response.error.code); NSLog(@"ERROR %ld",(long)response.statusCode);}];
```

But the error codes I expect was like

```
"errors":[
      {
         "status": 409,
         "code": "surge",
         "title": "Surge pricing is currently in effect for this product."
      }
   ].
```

Presently I'm getting only "status"(response.error.status) and "code" (response.error.code) and "title"(response.error.title) are "null" . I needed this "title"to display the error alert.
Will this data be available in production mode?

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: @Anbu.karthik, Below is the code                                                [[UberHelper sharedInstance].ridesClient requestRideWithParameters:_rideParameters completion:^(UBSDKRide * _Nullable ride, UBSDKResponse * _Nonnull response) {   NSLog(@"ERROR %@",response.error.title);
                NSLog(@"ERROR %@",response.error.code);
                NSLog(@"ERROR %ld",(long)response.statusCode);}];

Comment: @Anbu.karthik, I'm getting "status":401 and "code":unauthorized, title:nil with the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this way to get the UBSDKError.

```
    if(response.error.errors){

                UBSDKError *uberError = [response.error.errors objectAtIndex:0];

                NSLog(@"title %@",uberError.title);
                NSLog(@"code %@",uberError.code);
}
```